# Cannot run docker-compose.yml covering mongodb, kafka, zookeper for CQRS in Spring Boot? Docker-compose Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I have a problem to run docker-compose.yml file covering mongodb, kafka, zookeper for CQRS in Spring Boot. I only focus on account-cmd to dockerize it now.

When I try to run this command shown below, zookeeper is always pulling.

```
docker-compose up --build
```

As I get this problem, I cannot test the app running on Docker.

How can I fix it?

Here is Dockerfile shown below

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim AS build

COPY pom.xml mvnw ./
COPY .mvn .mvn
RUN ./mvnw dependency:resolve

COPY src src
RUN ./mvnw package -Dmaven.test.skip

FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
WORKDIR account-cmd
COPY --from=build target/*.jar account-cmd.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "account-cmd.jar"]
```

Here is docker-compose.yml shown below

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  app:
    image: 'account-cmd:latest'
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "5000:8080"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - mongodb
    environment:
      - kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=broker:9092
      - kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      - kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      - spring.data.mongodb.host=mongodb
      - spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
      - spring.data.mongodb.database=bankAccount
      - server.port=5000
    networks:
      - bankAccount


  mongodb:
    image: "mongo:latest"
    container_name: mongo-container
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db
    networks:
      - bankAccount

  zookeeper:
    image: "bitnami/zookeeper"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - "zookeeper_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    networks:
      - bankAccount

  kafka:
    image: "bitnami/kafka"
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "kafka_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - bankAccount


volumes:
  mongodb_data_container:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  bankAccount:
```

Here is my repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/cqrs-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After revised the **Dockerfile** and removing **maven** build form cqrs.core, the issue disappeared.

Here is the Dockerfile shown below

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar

COPY ${JAR_FILE} account.cmd.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/account.cmd.jar"]

EXPOSE 5000
```

Comment: Maven works fine in Docker